# How to close previous window when it redirects to another window in wpf mvvm using caliburn micro?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using caliburn micro in my project with mvvm architecure. I created on user control with a single button. when i click on the button it is redirecting to another user control. But the problem is when i redirect to another window, it is attaching to the previous window.
So, can any one help me to how to close the previous window when it redirects to another window.?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the way I would go about solving this issue is use IoC/MEF to get a reference to the window manager, do a WindowManager.CreateWindow(NewViewModel) to open a new window, then TryClose() the old window.